# Why is an object utilized by Angular undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, object, undefined

I'm fairly new to Angular. Here is a controller I'm working on...

```
svs.controller('registrationCtrl', function($scope, validatorService) {
  $scope.$watch("registrationForm.email.value", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (validatorService.validateEmail(newValue))  {
      $scope.registrationForm.email.valid = true;
    } else {
      $scope.registrationForm.email.valid = false;
    }
  });
});
```

On the associated view, there is a text input for the user's email. It's set to have Angular use `$scope.registrationForm.email.value` as the model. This seems to be the case, as if I remove everything from inside the `$watch` function, and just do a simple console log, it logs whenever I change the value of the text input.

The idea here is to have an object at `$scope.registrationForm` that looks similar to this...

```
{
  email: {
    value: "someEmail@emailProvider.com",
    valid: true
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to watch the value of the text area, use a service method to validate the email, and setting the `valid` property of `registrationForm.email` to `true` when it is valid.

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error...

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined`

I have not explicitly defined in the JavaScript `registrationForm.email.valid`, nor have I made any reference to it in the HTML of my view.

Do I need to create this property before setting it? What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you have to create a property before setting.

```
$scope.email={};
```

Comment: You were correct. What I ended up doing is creating a service which has a method to create form objects. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do it like this, because... angular already makes it.
Everything you need is adding attribute name to form and to input.

```
    <script>
  angular.module('emailExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.email = {
        text: 'me@example.com'
      };
    }]);
</script>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>Email:
      <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text" required>
    </label>
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
        Required!</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.email">
        Not valid email!</span>
    </div>
    <tt>text = {{email.text}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.email = {{!!myForm.$error.email}}</tt><br/>
  </form>
```

More details available [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D)